# SCons and dependencies for python function generating source

Tags: python, scons

**edit** Totally rewritten example, the issue is the same.

I have `SConsctruct` file:

```
env = Environment()

def write_main( out ):
    out.write("""
              #include <iostream>

              int main(int argc, char **argv)
              {{
                std::cout << "[{0}]" << std::endl;
                return 0;
              }}

              \n""".format(ARGUMENTS.get('print', 'nothing'))
            )

def generate_main(env, target, source):
    with open( env.GetBuildPath( target[0] ), 'w') as out:
        write_main( out )

main_builder = env.Builder( action = generate_main )
main_cpp = main_builder( env, env.GetBuildPath('main.cpp'), [] )

prog = env.Program( target='main', source=main_cpp )
```

Now if I run:

```
$ scons print=one && ./main 
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
generate_main(["main.cpp"], [])
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o
scons: done building targets.
[one]

$ scons print=two && ./main
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
[one]

$ rm main.cpp
$ scons print=two && ./main
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
generate_main(["main.cpp"], [])
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o
scons: done building targets.
[two]
```

So you can clearly see that the middle build was incorrect.
How can this be solved?

**note**: If I move body of `write_main` to `generate_main` (so I have only one function) it rebuilds correctly.

**note**:

One solution I can think of is providing all functions with `target` object so they can call `Depends` explicitly. In that example that would mean calling something like:

```
Depends( target, env.Variable( ARGUMENTS.get('print', 'nothing') ) )
```

Is there any other approach which would allow me to maintain current signature of `write_main` without requiring any knowledge about it in `generate_main`?

And how do I enforce particular syntax highlighting for a piece of code? (in above shell output gets weird/incorrect colors)

Comment: Some more detail from the important parts of the SConstruct and/or SConscript would be helpful

Comment: @Brady: I have rewrote the whole question. Now you get minimal working example that consists only of SConstruct file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create explicit dependencies in SCons using the [Depends](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x1220.html)() function.

Comment: That I know. However I am not able to track all references/relations of functions (or at least I am too lazy to) and that's why I want the tool to do this for me.
I prefer it to build it even if it doesn't have to, then skip cases when it is required, but I am looking for a solution other to "always build".

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have already figured out that the basic issue is that SCons does not know the content of your generated `main.cpp` file at analysis time. Therefore it simply does not rebuild on your second run because no dependencies has changed. What you need is to make the `env.Builder( action = generate_main )` builder depend on the input argument. In that way, if the input argument change it will rebuild the `main.cpp`.
There are several ways to obtain this. One way I can think of, is to add your argument to the env, as the builders take the env into account when building. It could look something like:

```
env.inputArguments = ARGUMENTS.get('print', 'nothing')
```

placed right above your `main_builder = env.Builder( action = generate_main )`

Hope it helps
Regards